# Is there a way my organization can collect clients' sensitive documents without being liable for them?

Tags: access-control, legal, file-upload

I am the head of IT for a microlending organization.  We make small loans to new businesses, and as such we have to collect these clients' tax returns and other financial data as part of the application process.  Currently this is done either by clients physically dropping them off at the office, or emailing them (obviously not very secure!).

We have to spend a lot of time prodding applicants to get us all of their required documents.  We'd like to be able to write a software system with a dashboard the client can log into, listing each of their still needed documents and an upload button. Periodically clients would get an email listing documents still needed.

Now I could write this system pretty easily if we just store the documents on our VPS and in our database. But, management (I assume rightly?) is concerned that storing documents on our server would increase our liability.

When I integrated a Stripe checkout form into an ecommerce site a few years ago, Javascript would intercept the form submission, send the credit card number to Stripe and get back a token, which would then be saved on my server.  The token could be used to charge the card, but there was no way to get the card number from the token.

Does anyone know of a way or a service that would allow something similar for sensitive documents?  Say the submission form could take the file attachment and send it to a service, and then the service sends back metadata about the file, but does not allow looking at the files' contents directly.

There doesn't seem to be a way to do this with Box, Dropbox, or Google Drive, and I don't think they are secure enough anyway.  Foldergrid.com looks promising, but there doesn't seem to be a way to send a file from the user's filesystem to their server via Javascript.  Javascript can't access the filesystem, and html forms can't send Ajax requests with content-type of json.

We can set up one time "dropzones" with Foldergrid where a user can, given a unique link, upload files to a folder without logging in.  However with this there is no way to know when certain documents have been uploaded (we want to send a notification to an employee when all of the documents are uploaded).

Perhaps we'll have to bite the bullet and become PCI-compliant or whatever certification is required to do this in a proper manner on our server, but does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: What, if any, liability you incur by adopting a particular software solution is a legal question, not an information security question. Try Law.SE. Also, product recommendations are off topic.

Comment: PCI compliance is for credit cards, not for other types of sensitive information.

Comment: Can you store them completely offline after getting them? Print them and put them in a safe? https://pciguru.files.wordpress.com/2013/12/200511-theultrasecurenetworkarchitecture.pdf for a "not entirely insecure" network layout

Comment: You need to define "liability" for your organization before you can find an answer to this. Liability for what? If you had a per-client encryption key, proper key management, and encrypted the documents before storing (on an encrypted drive), then you have lowered your risk of the data being accessed by unauthorized parties. Is that what you mean?

Comment: You're already liable to be GLBA compliant for handling sensitive customer/financial data. (if you're in the US or doing business with a US company) Please review: https://www.ftc.gov/tips-advice/business-center/privacy-and-security/gramm-leach-bliley-act

Comment: @JustinLardinois you are right that part of this is a legal issue. And I'm not so much looking for a product recommendation as I am advice on how to do this in general.  Is offloading the storing of sensitive documents a viable security policy?  Sorry if this isn't the right place to ask this.

Comment: @k1DBLITZ thanks for posting this link, I was not aware of these guidelines.  Having never worked on a site with this level of data sensitivity I'm not fully sure where to begin.

Comment: Whatever requirements you would need (e.g. Data Protection Directive) your partner site would need to implement too, but you would also need to build a secure channel between them and you and you'd still need to take reasonable steps to ensure your infrastructure (especially, the machines from which you'll retrieve the files on the partner site) is secure. The data protection directive doesn't define what "reasonable effort" to secure means, though.